# How to make a text bold in helper.rb ruby file inside a string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have one mailer file called schedule_mailer.html.erb
in that I'm trying to use a helper method from that I'm rendering the contents

in scheudle_mailer.html.erb

```
<p style='font-size:15px;margin:0 25px 20px 25px' >
  <%= body_text_tag() %>
</p>
```

in helper.rb
i need to send a string which includes `<b>` as well as `<br>`
but I'm receiving in mail as `<b>` and `<br>` tag itself.

my helper method

```
def body_text_tag()
      body = "This email to inform you that"
        if @creation 
          body +  "your hotel schedule has been created <br>
          <b>timings :</b>  #{@timings}, <br>
          <b>Room number :</b> #{@room number},<br>
          ....
          ....
          ....
        elsif ....
       .....
end.
```

as I have tried tag(:br), inside the string, even though it's rendering the mail with the tag(:br) itself, instead of the break line.
how to approach this kind of tags in the string to HTML?

Comment: Why don't you simply use ERB directly in this case or a partial for each case? Why calling a helper from ERB and building HTML with string concatenation?

Comment: @spickermann as the same content has been used across multiple email templates with the same instance variables, so that's why i try to implement with helper

Comment: As @spickermann says you should write partials instead in ERB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that in Rails when you append a normal string to [a safe buffer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) its automatically escaped to prevent XSS attacks.

```
irb(main):076:0> "<b>Hello".html_safe + "World</b>"
=> "<b>HelloWorld&lt;/b&gt;"
```

If you want to create text that contains HTML tags from a helper you need to mark the portions that are HTML tags as safe:

```
"<b>".html_safe + @timings + "</b>".html_safe
```

Do not do:

```
"<b>#{ @timings }</b>".html_safe
```

Unless you actually know that the content is actually safe and doesn't contain user input.

This is what [the tag helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) do automatically for you:

```
content_tag(:b, @timings)
tag.b(@timings)
```

But this code most likely doesn't actually belong in a helper in the first place. Use a view or a partial and write it in ERB.

Answer (score -2):

one of the solutions which I tried and worked for me is to use html_safe, in the mailer.
as
<%= body_text_tag().html_safe %>

Comment: That my friend is how you get an XSS attack. Do you actually know that entire string is safe? I'm guessing no. https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-how-to-use-html_safe-correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).